# BMS transformation of Twistors at Infinity

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, twistor

As the title suggest, is it known how a twistor variable will transform under the action of BMS transformation? Consider the [2-twistor construction on Null Infinity](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/1/1/005). One suggestion that I got online was to consider Lie-derivative of a twistor $Z^{\alpha}=(\omega^A,\pi_{A'})$ w.r.t BMS vector $\xi$. Since $\xi$ acts as a Conformal Killing vector field on $\mathscr{I}$ , $\mathcal{L}_{\xi}Z^{\alpha}$ will also satisfy the twistor equation. However, the expression of $\xi$ on null infinity involves two independent choice of 2-twistors (see eqn (3) and (11) from the above linked article). If we denote them as $(Z,\tilde{Z})$, it follows
$$\mathcal{L}_{\xi}Z=\delta Z = \delta Z (Z,\tilde{Z},\bar{Z},\bar{\tilde{Z}})$$
The system of two independent twistors $Z$ and $\tilde{Z}$ changes simultaneously, which is odd considering original transformation proposed by Penrose involved only one variable (and it's c.c.) ([see here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00668831#:%7E:text=It%20is%20suggested%20that%20twistors,%27momentum%27%20operators%2C%20respectively.)):
$$\delta Z = \frac{\partial H (Z,\bar{Z})}{\partial \bar{Z}}$$
The above symplectic transformation also appears in [non-linear graviton construction](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00763433). However, I am not sure if this form still holds at the null infinity of a  real-lorentzian manifold and in presence of matter-field .